# Negative Values for Auto-Generated Keys returned by Oracle DB 19c

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc, oracle19c

We're using IDENTITY column in Oracle database(19c) for the primary key of our table.

For some internal logics, we're using getAutoGeneratedKeys() to get the IDs of entities created. But the IDs returned in the result set have some discrepancies in them.

Following is the code to get the auto-generated keys.

```
String keyCols[] = {"ID"};  
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(queryToInsertEntity, keyCols);  
        ps.executeBatch();  
        resultSet = ps.getGeneratedKeys();  
        while (resultSet.next()) {  
            logger.trace("Entity ID:{}", resultSet.getBigDecimal(1));  
        }
```

For example, for couple of entities the ID returned by resultset is something like the one (with negative values):
Entity ID: -4.3692522E-31

And, for couple of entities the ID returned is as follows
Entity ID: 1591017024

So the question is why the resultSet.getBigDecimal() is returning different values at different times. An entity can never have negative ID as the min value for Identity column is 1.

Is it somewhere related to getAutoGeneratedKeys() method?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Not only is it negative, but `E-31`?! If some code in the database manipulates with that value, try to search for it using `select * from user_source where lower(text) like '%entity_id%'` (or whichever column name it is). Yes, you might get A LOT of results.

Comment: @Littlefoot, The mentioned query returned 0 rows. Also, It seems like it is somewhere related to getGeneratedKeys() method. Is there any limit on the number of entries that this getGenerateKeys() method can support. We're trying to insert 2-3k entries in a single batch.

Comment: I don't know Java nor any of stuff you use, sorry. I thought that it might be somewhere in the database itself, but - apparently - it is not. Unfortunately, I can't assist any further, but I hope someone else can. Good luck!